# Changing auto-layout constraints at runtime in table cell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have subclassed a UITableViewCell which has a bunch of buttons and labels created in IB which all have outlets. What I'm trying to do is, depending on the content of the cell, a UIButton needs to move slightly up, or remain in its place. I created an outlet for the constraint which needs to change so that I can change it in code.

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I have the following:

```
[cell.usernameButton.superview removeConstraint:cell.usernameTopConstraint];
int topDistance;
// code to conditionally change topDistance for constraint is omitted here, results in either 5 or 15

cell.usernameTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.usernameButton
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:cell.usernameButton.superview
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:topDistance];

[cell.usernameButton.superview addConstraint:cell.usernameTopConstraint];
[cell.usernameButton.superview layoutIfNeeded];
```

The problem is, the existing constraint must not get removed, because I get the error: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" - the two it shows me are the two that can get applied above.

Oddly, when I log `cell.usernameButton.superview`, it's null for every cell until a cell with the non-default topDistance which throws the constraint error. Then it's set for every cell drawn afterwords.

Why isn't the constraint getting removed? I've tried a bunch of different ways of referencing the button's superview, none of which seem to work.

Comment: Why don't you change the constant instead of removing and re-adding the constraint?

Comment: @jturton that worked. I had tried doing that by redefining the constraint entirely which didn't work. But I tried it by doing `cell.usernameConstraint.constant = topDistance` and that worked. Care to add this as an answer? And I'll accept.

Comment: I'm still curious why I couldn't remove the constraint....

Comment: Done. You couldn't remove the constraint because the superview was nil, so you weren't removing it from anything. As to _why_ the superview was nil, I have no idea. It's hard to say without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change the constant instead of removing and re-adding the constraint?

```
cell.usernameConstraint.constant = topDistance;
```

Comment: i am trying this but the constraints not changing

Comment: @MANCHIKANTIKRISHNAKISHORE call `layoutIfNeeded`